# python3 CSV TypeError ValueError _csv.Error

Tags: python-3.x

I follow a learning project on Udemy called
"30 Days of Python | Unlock your Python Potential"
And this is the courese of Day16

Here is my code

```
filename = "data.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ["id", "name", "email", "amount", "sent"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    #writer.writeheader()


for row in reader:
    print(row)
    writer.writerow({
            "id": row["id"],
            "name": row["name"],
            "email": row["email"],
            "amount": "1293.23",
            "sent": ""
        })
```

I get an error though I checked that my code is the same as teacher's code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hungry_data.py", line 36, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Users\Another\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\csv.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "C:\Users\Another\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Therefore I changed code from "rb" to "r" .... `with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, temp_file:`

and this way too

```
with open(filename, "r", newline='') as csvfile, temp_file:
```

But Get the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hungry_data.py", line 43, in <module>
    "sent": ""
  File "C:\Users\Another\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Another\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

It seems that the line 36 have a conflict with line 43
how should I do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to open file in write mode.

```
with open(filename, "w")
```

Your exception raised cause U try to write to file opened only for reading, if you want to read and write from file use

```
with open(filename, "+")
```

[source python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Also your exception may be raised, cause U open your file in 'rb' mode, where b is reading in bytes. Try to remove b from mode